# Javascript/jquery for loop array

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, each

I am new to Javascript and Jquery and am writting a script that changes CSS 'transform' values when the mouse moves within the browser window to make an image change perspective.

Everything is working great! I just want to streamline my javascript/jquery to reduce the amount of code (as I am CSS targeting -webkit- -moz- -ms- etc) and also make tweaking the script easier.

Ok so here is the part I want to streamline:

```
$('#logo').css({

'-webkit-transform': 
"rotateY("
 + (e.pageX-(current_width/2))/150 + 
"deg) rotateX("
 + (e.pageY-(e.pageY*2-600)-(current_height/2))/300 + 
"deg)", 

  '-moz-transform': 
"rotateY("
 + (e.pageX-(current_width/2))/150 + 
"deg) rotateX("
 + (e.pageY-(e.pageY*2-600)-(current_height/2))/300 + 
"deg)", 

  '-ms-transform': 
"rotateY("
 + (e.pageX-(current_width/2))/150 + 
"deg) rotateX("
 + (e.pageY-(e.pageY*2-600)-(current_height/2))/300 + 
"deg)", 

  'transform': 
"rotateY("
 + (e.pageX-(current_width/2))/150 + 
"deg) rotateX("
 + (e.pageY-(e.pageY*2-600)-(current_height/2))/300 + 
"deg)", 

  });
```

As you can see the only variation in each of the 4 central sections is the CSS browser specific elements (-webkit-, -moz-, etc) so naturally I want to create an array that will contain each of these variations and then loop through the variations.

This is my first attempt using javascript "for" to loop:

```
var browserTransitionCSS = [
    '-webkit-transition',
    '-moz-transition',
    '-ms-transition',
    'transition'
    ];


   for(var i=0; i < browserTransformCSS.length; i++) 
            {
$('#logo').css({
browserTransformCSS: 
     "rotateY("
     + (e.pageX-(current_width/2))/150 + 
     "deg) rotateX("
      + (e.pageY-(e.pageY*2-600)-(current_height/2))/200 + 
     "deg)", 
  });
};
```

This is my second attempt using Jquery "each" to loop:

```
var browserTransitionCSS = [
    '-webkit-transition',
    '-moz-transition',
    '-ms-transition',
    'transition'
    ];


$.each(browserTransitionCSS, function(something) { 
$('#logo').css({ 
something :  
"rotateY("
 + (e.pageX-(current_width/2))/150 + 
"deg) rotateX("
 + (e.pageY-(e.pageY*2-600)-(current_height/2))/200 
+ "deg)", 
                });
            });
```

And now, after hours of struggling, I am giving in and asking if anyone can please help me.

If it would be helpful to see my url then please ask.

Any help here would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok I'm still not quite there so have coded a working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/asy9u/5/. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I would do something like this :

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var current_width  = $(window).width(),
        current_height = $(window).height(),
        y = (e.pageX - (current_width / 2)) / 150,
        x = (e.pageY - (e.pageY * 2 - 600) - (current_height / 2)) / 300;

    $('#logo').css( transformObj(x,y) );
});

function transformObj(x,y) {
    var pfx = ['-webkit-transform','-moz-transform','-ms-transform','transform'],
        obj = {};

    $.each(pfx, function(k,val) {
        obj[val] = "rotateY("+y+"deg) rotateX("+x+"deg)";
    });
    return obj;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/asy9u/4/)

Creating the object passed to jQuery's `css()` method in a seperate function where you iterate the browser prefixes and apply the `X` and `Y` rotation to each one, then passing it back to `css()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have not included all my code in my first extract and this may have caused confusion. My code works perfectly for what I need it to do however I just want to know how I can shorten the code. Instead of: 
'-webkit-transform': ALL THE CODE,
'-moz-transform': ALL THE CODE etc
I just want to put: Array = '-webkit-transform', '-moz-transform' etc.
Now loop around this:
Array : ALL THE CODE

Comment: @MichaelWalkling - I added the mousemove for demonstrational purposes, but the code above should show you a pretty good example of how to iterate the browser prefixed transform properties, and apply a value to the object, and how to pass it to `.css( object ) etc`

Comment: Thanks again but I'm still not quite getting this. I have coded a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/asy9u/5/. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MichaelWalkling - And using something like in the above code, that fiddle would look like [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/asy9u/7/), iterating the array, and setting the x and y values ?

Comment: Thats great! Thank you very much! Sorted

Answer (score 0):

The first argument you'll receive in the function you pass to each will be the index of the element (if the object you're going over is an array) or a key (if it's an associative array).

Try:

```
$.each(browserTransitionCSS, function(i, element) { 
    ... and so on
```

Inside the function you'd be receiving each transition element: "-webkit-transition", "-moz-transition" as the `element` argument. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this: $.each(browserTransitionCSS, function(i, element) { 
$('#logo').css({ 
something :  
"rotateY(" etc. But this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

How to use: for loop till 360 angels, below is one line, it have to rotate for 24 
lines with same distance.

```
#straight{
height: 30px;
border-right: 1px solid blue; 
-webkit-transform: rotate(45 deg);
transform: rotate(45 deg); 
position: absolute;
}
```